# SELECT INTO local variable undeclared?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following in an sql file I am executing...

```
DECLARE rowcount INT;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rowcount
FROM VRG_PROBLEM_ACCOUNT PA 
WHERE NEW.CustName = PA.CustNAME 
AND NEW.AreaCode = PA.AreaCode 
AND NEW.PhoneNumber = PA.PhoneNumber;
```

And yet I'm getting

```
ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: rowcount
```

In another file I am doing the same type of SELECT...INTO localvariable and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local variables can only be declared inside of stored routines. You can use @-variables instead, which don't need to be declared at all:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @rowcount
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about re-writing your query a bit?

```
DECLARE rowcount INT;

SET rowcount = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM VRG_PROBLEM_ACCOUNT PA 
     WHERE PA.CustNAME = NEW.CustName
       AND PA.AreaCode = NEW.AreaCode
       AND PA.PhoneNumber = NEW.PhoneNumber);
```

**UPDATE 1***

I do not know your full code, but please keep in mind that `DECLARE` is permitted only inside a `BEGIN ... END` compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.

Comment: That won't make a difference.

Comment: Do you use this query inside a `TRIGGER`?